# Detect page changes in webextension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am building an extension for a specific website. It sets an element width to certain size:

```
//script.js
document.getElementById('nice header').style.width = "100px";
```

Here is my manifest (relevant parts):

```
{
    "content_scripts": [
      {
          "matches": [ "https://target_website.com/*" ],
          "js": [ "script.js" ]
      }
    ]
}
```

While debugging the extension, when I enter the `target_website.com` first time, I see my changes applied. However, if I navigate somewhere inside this site, e.g. to `target_website.com/profile`, the element with id `nice header` width is set to its original value. If I then reload this page, then the changes from my extension are applied again.

How can I ensure changes in my extension are always applied to the website?

Comment: Try adding `"all_frames": true`

Comment: @PrerakSola Thank you for your reply, that did not help.

Comment: Is the page reloaded when you navigate to `/profile`? Or just the path changes like in an angular app?

Comment: @PrerakSola I believe just the path changes, not the whole page reloads.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to listen to [onUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated) event of the `chrome.tabs` API in a background script. And upon detection send a message to your content script to execute the required code.

Comment: Thanks, will try that!

Comment: If even that doesn't work, you can try this listener instead of onUpdated.
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onHistoryStateUpdated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the site you are targeting uses some kind of Single Page Application technology.

To apply simple, styling changes, I would recommend using a custom CSS file instead of a script:

```css
#nice_header {
    width: 100px; /* maybe add an !important here */
}
```

then include it in your manifest.json:

```
...
{
    "content_scripts": [
      {
          "matches": [ "https://target_website.com/*" ],
          "css": [ "style.css" ],
          "js": [ "script.js" ]
      }
    ]
}
...
```

This will not only persist your setting but saves CPU cycles for your users.

If you would like to perform JavaScript function on every page change, you might need to subscribe to `webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated` event.
More information on that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webNavigation/onHistoryStateUpdated